# How to set DataTables default sEmptyTable value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am having trouble setting the value of our datatables default sEmptyTable value like so:

```
table.fnSettings().oLanguage.sEmptyTable = "There are no customers currently marked “In Dealership” to display";
```

this is for a certain table.  For the rest of the tables in our jquery.dataTables.js file we have this set as the default:

```
"sEmptyTable": "No data available in table",
```

which is what shows still.  Is there a way to over write the default with a new one for a particular table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yes, you can override the internationalisation active, did you tried this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mytable').dataTable({
      "oLanguage": {
        "sEmptyTable": "Overriding value ..."
      }
    });
});
```

for further details check [here](http://www.datatables.net/usage/i18n)

Comment: Is there no way to change this globally, instead of having to set this language override on every single table in the application?